# Control panel windows open in an nonexistent screen in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have Windows 7 and I am using only one monitor.
When I try to open any configuration window from Control Panel, the window opens into an nonexistent monitor, they "fly" to the right of the monitor and I can't see and can't use them.

I never had a dual monitor setup, but I can't even enter in the Graphics configurations, because the window will open in the nonexistent screen.

How can I bring back control panel on my screen so I can make use of it?

Comment: Are all the windows opening on the second screen?

Edit: Try selecting the window in the taskbar, and using Win+Shift+Arrow keys. That should move the window to the actual monitor you are working on. Then go to graphics settings, and make sure there is only one monitor selected.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot! Using the keys I could bring it back and then I fixed the graphics settings. Someone connected the monitor using both the VGA and HDMI cable, so Windows 7 thought I have two monitors, funny :)

Comment: That's what happens when people do random BS. Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all the windows opening on the second screen? Edit: Try selecting the window in the taskbar, and using Win+Shift+Arrow keys. That should move the window to the actual monitor you are working on. Then go to graphics settings, and make sure there is only one monitor selected.